# Почему не проходит мой вариант функции?

Tags: javascript, promise

Написать функцию **increaseSalary**, которая будет увеличивать зарплату сотруднику с наименьшей зарплатой.

Вам нужно

1. Получает данные по всем работникам
2. Находит работника с наименьшей зарплатой
3. Отправляет запрос на повышение зарплаты этому сотруднику на 20%
4. Если запрос прошел успешно - отправить сотруднику уведомление об
   увеличении ЗП тектом: Hello, <имя>! Congratulations, your new salary
   is <новая ЗП>!
5. Если запрос завершился неудачей - отправить данные об ошибке
   администратору текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом

Должна всегда возвращать resolved промис с boolean значением:

true если увеличение прошло успешно
false если нет
Все функции для получения/изменения данных асинхронны и возвращают промисы.
Вам предоставлены функции:

```
api.getEmployees(); // Возвращает массив с объектами {id: 343, name: 'Alex', salary: 20000}
api.setEmployeeSalary(employeeId, newSalary); // Принимает id сотрудника и новую зарплату. Возвращает новые данные по сотруднику.
api.notifyEmployee(employeeId, text); // Принимает id сотрудника и текст уведомления
api.notifyAdmin(error); // Принимает ошибку
```

```
function increaseSalary() {
    return api.getEmployees()
        .then(employeeData => {
            const [minSalaryEmployee] = employeeData.reduce(([minEmployee, minSalary], employee) => {
                const {salary} = employee;
                return (salary < minSalary
                    ? [employee, salary]
                    : [minEmployee, minSalary]
                );
            }, [null, Infinity]);
            const {id, salary: oldSalary} = minSalaryEmployee;
            const newSalary = oldSalary * 1.2;
            return {id, salary: newSalary};
        })
        .then(({id, salary}) => api.setEmployeeSalary(id, salary))
        .then(({name, id, salary}) => api.notifyEmployee(id, `Hello, ${name}! Congratulations, your new salary is ${salary}!`))
        .catch(e => api.notifyAdmin(e));
}
```

```
const api = {
  _employees: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alex', salary: 120000 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Fred', salary: 110000 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Bob', salary: 80000 },
  ],

  getEmployees() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(this._employees.slice());
    });
  },

  setEmployeeSalary(employeeId, newSalary) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this._employees = this._employees.map((employee) =>
        employee.id !== employeeId
          ? employee
          : {
            ...employee,
            salary: newSalary,
          }
      );
      resolve(this._employees.find(({ id }) => id === employeeId));
    });
  },

  notifyEmployee(employeeId, text) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(true);
    });
  },

  notifyAdmin(error) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(true);
    });
  },

  setEmployees(newEmployees) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this._employees = newEmployees;
      resolve();
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Что значит "не проходит мой вариант фукнции"? Я составил ответ, который доказывает, что все работает, где я у себя никаких ошибок не воспроизвел.

Answer (score 0):

Я попробовал у себя что-то воспроизвести и есть подозрение, что-то не так с клиентским кодом, где функция вызывается.

Функция, которая возвращает промис должна вызываться так и вам об этом прекрасно известно же:

```
console.log(api._employees);
increaseSalary().then(isOk => {
    console.log(isOk);
    console.log(api._employees);
})
```

Вывод:

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'Alex', salary: 120000 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Fred', salary: 110000 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Bob', salary: 80000 }  // Самый низкооплачиваемый сотрудник
]
true
[
  { id: 1, name: 'Alex', salary: 120000 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Fred', salary: 110000 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Bob', salary: 96000 }  // Теперь зп +20%
]
```

Все работает абслютно правильно, судя по заданию.